# Multiline PCRE, multiple conditions

Tags: regex, pcre

just starting out with regex and have hit a stumbling block. Hoping someone might be able to explain the workaround.

Trying to carry out a multi-line search. I wish to use "*" as the 'flag', so to speak: if a line contains an asterisk it should match. The digits at the start of the line should be output, so should the word "Match" in the linked example, excluding the asterisk itself.

I assume my use of "|" is dividing the regex into two conditions, when it actually needs to satisfy both to match.

https://regex101.com/r/Pu56bi/2

```
(?m)(^\d+)|(?<=\*).*$
```

Any help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pos. lookahead as in

```
^(?=.*?\*)(\d+).+?(Match)$
```

See [**your modified example on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Pu56bi/2).

Comment: Thank you for this input Jan. My example was unclear, I just wished to match the rest of the line, as opposed to the literal word 'Match'.

I updated my regex to the below using your guidance: 
(?m)(?=.*?\*)(\d+)|(\*\w*).*$

https://regex101.com/r/SQzmw9/2

Is it further possible to 'match until'?

https://regex101.com/r/bRQkWM/1

Answer (score 0):

If `Match` is always at the end of the string, you could match the digits at the start of the string, then match an `*` and `Match` at the end of the string.

Use a word boundary `\b` to prevent the word of digits being part of a longer word.

```
^(\d+)\b.*\*.*\b(Match)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQzmw9/1)

If there can be test after the word `Match` you can assert `*` using a positive lookahead.

```
^(?=.*\*)(\d+)\b.*\b(Match)\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ii9S5E/1)